# Repeat a task with the "at" command everyday at 6PM

Tags: shell-script, scheduling, at

I want to repeat a task every day at 6PM.

I know this command executes a task at the next 6PM:

```
echo "ls -l" | at 18:00
```

I tried to RTFM but didn't find anything relevant to repeating said task. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to print the string `ls -l` or do you want to run the command `ls -l` every day at 18:00?

Comment: `at` is for running a job one time.  `cron` is for running a reoccurring job at a regular schedule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`man cron` is your friend. For this, you might want to try something like:

```
0 18 * * * echo "ls -l" > /var/log/ls_log.log
```

Add it to the crontab with `crontab -e`. Check the output of the command by looking at `/var/log/ls_log.log`. Google "cron tutorial"- there are lots of them

Comment: Does this persist across system restarts? This is for a raspberry pi.

Comment: It should, yes. `cron` starts a deamon that reads from the crontab on startup.

Comment: @shashankan if you type `man cron` into your terminal, it tells you this. though not succintly